# mvc3 prompt System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, internationalization, data-annotations

I am using translation from resx files stored in `App_GlobalResources` folder with DataAnnotations in a mvc3 model.

It works fine with a `Required DataAnnotation`, but it doesn't work any more if i'm trying to use the `Display DataAnnotation`.

Here is my code:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Error), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredClientName")]
[Display(Prompt = "ClientName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Front))]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

A `System.InvalidOperationException` is thrown only when I put the `Display DataAnnotation`

Here is the full exception(I am sorry, I didn't find a way to translate it in english):

> Impossible de récupérer la propriété 'Prompt' en raison de l'échec de
>   la localisation. Le type 'Resources.Front' n'est pas public ou ne
>   contient pas une propriété de chaîne statique publique avec le nom
>   'FooterAbout'.
>
> Description : Une exception non gérée s'est produite au moment de
>   l'exécution de la requête Web actuelle. Contrôlez la trace de la pile
>   pour plus d'informations sur l'erreur et son origine dans le code.
>
> Détails de l'exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Impossible
>   de récupérer la propriété 'Prompt' en raison de l'échec de la
>   localisation. Le type 'Resources.Front' n'est pas public ou ne
>   contient pas une propriété de chaîne statique publique avec le nom
>   'FooterAbout'.

The model I am using is stored in an `Area`.
Also, I can access values in my resx files from the `_Layout`, or in the `Required DataAnnotation`

Thank you for your help

Florent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty self explanatory (which I am translating for the non-French speaking audience of the site):

> Cannot retrieve property 'Prompt' because localization failed.  Type
>   'Resources.Front' is not public or does not contain a public static
>   string property with the name 'ClientName'.

You should make the resource file public by setting the Custom Tool to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` and the Build Action to `Embedded Resource` in the properties of your RESX file:

[image]

The reason for that is because by default the generated strongly typed class is internal and not accessible by Razor views which are compiled into a separate assembly at runtime.